# Chrome Extension using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a very simple Chrome Extension with a jQuery menu - it's based in some code I gathered online. When I test the HTML in a browser it works, the problem is when I test as a Chrome Extension.

Is there anything missing in the manifest file?

Thanks

Here are the files:

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "name",
"description": "desc",
"version": "1.4",

"manifest_version": 2,

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "ari.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
                    },
  "permissions": [
            "tabs",
            "http://*/",
            "https://*/",
            "file:///*/*",
            "https://*.google.com/"
            ]

"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*"]
    "js": [
           "jquery.js",
           "popup.js"
          ],
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>title</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>

<style>
</style>

<!--
  - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
  - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
  -
  - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
-->



</head>

<body>

<div style="float:left" > <!--This is the first division of left-->
<p><strong>Report by region</strong></p>
<div id="firstpane" class="menu_list"> <!--Code for menu starts here-->
    <p class="menu_head">Header-1</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
    <a href="#">Link-1</a>
     <a href="#">Link-2</a>
     <a href="#">Link-3</a> 
    </div>
    <p class="menu_head">Header-2</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
        <a href="#">Link-1</a>
     <a href="#">Link-2</a>
     <a href="#">Link-3</a> 
    </div>
    <p class="menu_head">Header-3</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
      <a href="#">Link-1</a>
     <a href="#">Link-2</a>
     <a href="#">Link-3</a>         
   </div>
</div>  <!--Code for menu ends here-->
</div>

<div style="float:left; margin-left:20px;"> <!--This is the second division of right-->
<p><strong>Works with mouse over</strong></p>
<div class="menu_list" id="secondpane"> <!--Code for menu starts here-->
    <p class="menu_head">Header-1</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
    <a href="#">Link-1</a>
     <a href="#">Link-2</a>
     <a href="#">Link-3</a> 
    </div>
    <p class="menu_head">Header-2</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
        <a href="#">Link-1</a>
     <a href="#">Link-2</a>
     <a href="#">Link-3</a> 
    </div>
    <p class="menu_head">Header-3</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
      <a href="#">Link-1</a>
     <a href="#">Link-2</a>
     <a href="#">Link-3</a>         
   </div>
</div>      <!--Code for menu ends here-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
<!--//---------------------------------+
//  Developed by Roshan Bhattarai 
//  Visit http://roshanbh.com.np for this script and more.
//  This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
// --------------------------------->

$(document).ready(function()
{
    //slides the element with class "menu_body" when paragraph with class "menu_head" is clicked 
    $("#firstpane p.menu_head").click(function()
{
    $(this).css({backgroundImage:"url(down.png)"}).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).siblings().css({backgroundImage:"url(left.png)"});
});
//slides the element with class "menu_body" when mouse is over the paragraph
$("#secondpane p.menu_head").mouseover(function()
{
     $(this).css({backgroundImage:"url(down.png)"}).next("div.menu_body").slideDown(500).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
     $(this).siblings().css({backgroundImage:"url(left.png)"});
});
});
```

Comment: The scripts for the popup should not be mentioned in the content-scripts section of the manifest. It is sufficient to have them in the `<head>` section of the popup.html. The `content-scripts` section in the manifest is for content scripts only.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some closing brackets

```
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["http://*/*"],
"js": [
       "jquery.js",
       "popup.js"
      ]
}]
```

Answer (score -1):

The manifest looks fine, so I'm suspecting a directory structure problem.

'not working' is a pretty broad description of your problem. Post some console out put and throw in what your directory structure look like too.